# Why does he use different modalities for the future events?

Tags: modal-verbs

> The Federal Government **will** today unveil a plan to increase public
>   school spending to 50 billion dollars for the next six years. Under
>   the proposed Gonski funding reforms, public schools **would** receive an
>   extra 14-and-a-half billion dollars. Catholic schools **would** get an
>   extra one-and-a-half billion dollars and independent schools an extra
>   one billion dollars. ([Aussie ABC News](http://www.abc.net.au/news/2013-04-14/abc-news/4627740))

For the three future events, the first case uses ‘will,’ and the others use ‘would.’ What semantic difference does the writer want to say?

Comment: I think this is Too Localised. The government **will** unveil the plan, because that's something that **will** definitely happen, in the opinion of the reporter. That plan involves **proposed** reforms (that may or may not happen), so the reporter refers to them using "conditional" verb forms.

Comment: I agree with @FumbleFingers. In addition I think this could probably be answered by a dictionary, because it seems the OP's confusion is due to a misunderstanding of what *would* means (see [definition #5 here](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/would)).

Comment: @WendiKidd Are you arguing for 5a or 5b? I suppose it could be b, but I think in fact the meaning is 5a, *to express a contingency or possibility*. MW, however, restricts this meaning to *the conclusion of a conditional sentence* which this is not. So your reference will not answer this question without further explanation. And in any event, how does OP distinguish that it is this which is meant and not another definition?

Comment: @@WendiKidd, StoneyB: Looks to me more like M-W's **2 c** *—used in auxiliary function to express plan or intention **<said we would come>***. But with a word/concept as slippery as this, it's not like you could expect M-W to give a definitive list of all possible usages. All they can really do is give typical examples with descriptions.

Comment: @WendiKidd♦: I'm pretty sure Listenever understands the basic difference between *will* and *would*, or s/he would hardly have put *different modalities* in the title. I just think we're being invited to interpret the mindset of a reporter who, per my comment to the answer, could have used *will* throughout if he'd wanted to achieve a different effect.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, StoneyB: Fair enough. From my perspective the question seemed answered by the definition, but I can see how that might not be the case :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The administration - the executive branch - definitely *will* reveal the plan, but it will take effect only **if** Parliament - the legislative branch - passes the necessary legislation. Its provisions therefore are hypothetical and are expressed with *would*.

Comment: Of course, if the reporter strongly endorsed the proposals and/or firmly believed they would in fact be put into effect, he might quite validly have used *will* throughout. But I think we're more in the realms of Lit Crit, rather than "stuff learners need to learn".

Comment: @FumbleFingers But Australia's current government holds only a minority of seats in Parliament, so this may be a very iffy proposition, regardless of the reporter's biases.

Comment: I didn't know that, but one weakened case doesn't detract from my general point. I actually hadn't even registered that it was Oz until your comment. But I quite admire [Julia Gillard](http://www.pm.gov.au/) (who was born in Wales, dear to my heart and near to my home). So even though I know next to nothing of Oz political machinations, I'd mentally upgrade the probability of those plans coming to fruition simply because I ***want*** her to win through.